# Writing JavaScript vars in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I'm trying to print out vars in the html code from the javascript (if anyone can clean up the JS that would be a bonus). I tried adding document.write but never worked. Basically I need the street and country to print out under the map.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
                );
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: coords,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Your current location!"
            });

        });
    }else {
        alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data
        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script> 

<style type="text/css">
#mapContainer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    border:10px solid #eaeaea;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()"> 
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following construct in place of document.write

```
var x= document.getElementById("mapContainer");
x.innerHTML="your content goes here";
```